# Need of paid business emails when you already have cPanel hosting account

Tags: dns, hosting, cpanel, provider, whm

I got a domain registered with GoDaddy recently. Also, I purchased their Professional email & paid for a year's service.
After purchasing my Hosting server I got a Cpanel Account. Digging into the various CPanel options, I came across the CPanel emails section which lets you create multiple mail accounts for your Domain. My question is, did I waste my money not knowing that CPanel offered me a facility to create Business emails? Should I start using CPanel mails & disown the GoDaddy pro mail service.
Also, CPanel offers to configure mail clients of your choice for mobile & desktop which sounds convenient & offers the same solution as my GoDaddy pro email offers.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how many emails you send out and if they are important (should reach recipient's inbox folder).

You don't mention how familiar you are with setting up email servers, however if you set up a new email server, on a new domain, there is a higher chance that your email will end up in recipient's spam folder, especially if your email server isn't configured right, and you send out a lot of emails.

The service you bought increase chances that email sent out from GoDaddy's email servers will end up in inbox instead of spam folder, because GoDaddy (should) have email servers with good reputation.

To answer your question, if you know how to configure the email server the right way, you could send out emails on your own, just like GoDaddy does, and save some money.

Comment: Thanks for your reply  @uu01. Yes, I can configure an email server with some basic expertise. But, as you mentioned those mails might reach in the recepient's spam box, its something that needs to be thought about.

Comment: Make sure to set up proper PTR (RDNS) and SPF records and you should be ready to go. Also, MXToolBox is your friend (https://mxtoolbox.com/SuperTool.aspx), especially blacklist and smtp section, be sure to check up on those in case anything goes wrong. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

You can use cPanel based web hosting for your business email. You can setup your Email apps (like android default email with this). Before setting up, you must add DKIM, SPF and DMARC records within DNS of related domain, that will help you to mark your emails as not spam.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. That should help..Thanks !